# Postgresql's built in COPY command with Parameterized Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a project where the front end is `react` and the backend is `ruby on rails` and uses a postgres DB. I want to be able to export the response from the following query using Postgresql's built in COPY command and send it to the front end.

```
query = <<-SQL
    SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDERS.STORE_ID = ? OFFSET ? LIMIT ?
SQL
query_result = Order.find_by_sql([query, store_id.to_i, offset.to_i, 600000])
```

As you can see, my ruby code uses `find_by_sql` to execute the query and this allows me to enter the values for the `?` placeholders. How do i fill these values in using Postgres Copy command? The query will return 600000 records so delegating the act of generating the CSV to PostgreSQL itself seems like a good idea. The issue is that I don't know how to do this when my query is parameterized to avoid SQL injection. Any help with sample ruby code would be great!

Comment: The pg gem provides a method for quoting and escaping strings, proper use of which should prevent SQL injection.  https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/TextEncoder/QuotedLiteral.html

Comment: @jjanes can you give example on how this would be used to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can still use `find_by_sql` and just include the COPY in the query like this:

```
query = <<-SQL
    COPY
    (SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDERS.STORE_ID = ? OFFSET ? LIMIT ?)
    to '/path/temp/output.txt' WITH CSV HEADER
SQL
query_result = Order.find_by_sql([query, store_id.to_i, offset.to_i, 600000])
```